# Proof continuity of a function with epsilon-delta

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

I quickly need help with a problem that seems to be fairly easy but I can't really do the final step:

Proof that the function $\frac{x-1}{x²+1}$ is continuus in $x = -1$
using the epsilon-delta-definition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. We want to pick a $\delta$ that such that
$$
\bigg|\frac{x-1}{x^{2}+1}+1\bigg|=\bigg|\frac{x(x+1)}{x^{2}+1}\bigg|\leq|x||x+1|<\epsilon.
$$

We are free top choose $\delta$ as we wish, and, in doing so, we will have a handle on making the $|x+1|$ term above as small as we want. To help us minimize $|x|$, let's see what happens if we would ensure $|x+1|<1/2$.

In this case,

$$
|x+1|<\frac{1}{2}\implies-\frac{1}{2}<x+1<\frac{1}{2}\implies-\frac{3}{2}<x<-\frac{1}{2}<\frac{3}{2}\implies |x|<\frac{3}{2}.
$$

Thus, if $|x+1|<1/2$, it follows that $|x||x+1|<\frac{3}{2}|x+1|$. If, in addition, we ensure that $\delta<\frac{2\epsilon}{3}$, it follows that $|x||x+1|<\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{2\epsilon}{3}=\epsilon$.

Therefore, choosing $\delta=\min\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}\epsilon\}$ works.

Comment: Awesome, now I understood it. Thanks!

Comment: One more question though: You said "see what happens if we could ensure |x + 1| < 1/2". Did you arbitrarily choose that value or does it have a reason? Could I pick any value, see what |x| must look like and then choose delta?

Comment: In this case yes. But if we had $|x|$ in the denominator, we would have to have chosen a number $<1$. Otherwise, we would $1/|x|$ would not be bounded. Usually, one picks a number, say $1$ or $\frac{1}{2}$, and adjusts it accordingly if there are problems of the aforementioned type.

Comment: Never mind, I got it thinking about it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

First write

$$\left|\frac{x-1}{x^2+1}+1\right|=\left|\frac{x(x+1)}{x^2+1}\right|\le |x|\,|x+1|$$

Second, restrict $x$, say for example $-3/2\le  x\le -1/2$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: My approach is now to say the whole term is <= |x-1| <= |x+1-(1+1)| <= |x+1|-|2|. Now I can choose delta = epsilon + |2| and finish the proof. Does that work? Sorry for bad TeXerino

Comment: Not quite.  You now have $$|x||x+1|\le \frac12 |x+1|<\epsilon$$whenever $|x+1|<\min(1/2,2\epsilon)$

Comment: Hmm, I don't really get that. Can you tell me how to complete the proof? Been trying to this for 2 hours now.

Comment: I need to run now.  What part did you not understand?  The only tools used were simple bounds.

Comment: Could you possibly write down the complete proof again? Or tell me whats wrong with mine?

Answer (score 0):

Your delta should be picked carefully so that $\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}
$ is nicely bounded.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: it might be that the OP (or anyone else coming across the question) needs some further insights, could you therefore elaborate a bit?

Comment: Yup, some further insides would help.