# Question regarding continuity ($\epsilon$-$\delta$)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

In this post: [Proof continuity of a function with epsilon-delta](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792185/proof-continuity-of-a-function-with-epsilon-delta)
people explained how to proof that $$f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x^2+1}$$
is continuous in $x_0 = -1$.
However, my solution is the following:
$$|f(x) - f(x_0)| = \left\lvert\frac{x-1}{x^2+1} - (-1)\right\rvert = \left\lvert\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right\rvert|x+1| \leq |x-(-1)|=|x-x_0|.$$
Then choose $\delta := \epsilon$ and we're done. Now this solution seems by far easier than the once presented in the given post. Are both correct, and if yes, why would you choose those over mine?

Comment: your way seems fine to me, and indeed better :-) Maybe you should spend some time explaining why $\left\lvert\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right\rvert \le 1$ though :-)

Comment: @Ant that is indeed the only "bigger" step to do in my proof, but not hard for one to follow either. I was just wondering why nobody came up with my "easier" proof where you avoid a lot of work and computing.

Comment: Well done.  Your approach is solid.  But it is not unique as in most cases there are multiple ways forward.  Regarding showing that $\left|\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right|\le 1$, we have both $\left|\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right|\le |x|$ and $\left|\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right|\le \frac{1}{|x|}$.

Comment: How would you show the step you left out, that $|\frac{x}{x^2+1}|\le1$?

Comment: The other method is a structured method and thus more power that it can handle all continuous function without knowing its form.